# Loading gallery image into app, Out Of Memory Error after 5th or 6th picture loaded

Tags: android, image, imageview, out-of-memory

I am constantly getting `Out Of Memory Errors` after loading 5 or 6 gallery images into my app.

I am calling `bitmap.recycle()` after every image is done loading so wondering why I am still getting `OOM` error?

This is how I handle gallery images:

1. press button from inside app that goes to gallery to select image
2. goes back to app, and copies the gallery image to app's external files directory
3. compress and rotate the image
4. load image into ImageView

   ```
   public static void compressAndRotateImage(Context context, String filename) {
   try {
       File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);

       // Decode image size
       BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
       BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o);

       // The new size we want to scale to
       final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 720;

       // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
       int scale = 1;
       while (o.outWidth/scale/2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) { scale*=2; }

       // Decode with inSampleSize
       BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       o2.inSampleSize = scale;
       Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o2);

       // Get orientation of picture
       ExifInterface exif = null;
       try { exif = new ExifInterface(context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + filename); } 
       catch (IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
       int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
       Log.i("ORIENTATION", Integer.toString(orientation));

       // Rotate image to portrait based on taken orientation
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       if (orientation == 6) { matrix.postRotate(90); }
       else if (orientation == 3) { matrix.postRotate(180); }
       else if (orientation == 8) { matrix.postRotate(270); }
       bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);

       // Save and compress file
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
       bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
       try { fos.flush(); fos.close(); } 
       catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

       bm.recycle();
       System.gc();
   } 
   catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
   ```

   }

   **Copies gallery image to app external files dir**

   ```
   private void copyGalleryImage(Uri uri) {
   String realPath = ImageHandler.getRealPathFromUri(this, uri);
   File galleryFile = new File(realPath);

   imgFilename = ImageHandler.getImageFilename(this);
   File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), imgFilename);
   GlobalMethods.copyFile(galleryFile, file);
   Log.i("IMAGE COPIED TO INTERNAL", imgFilename);

   ImageHandler.compressAndRotateImage(this, imgFilename);
   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
   NewPictureFragment fragment = NewPictureFragment.newInstance(imgFilename);
   ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
   ft.addToBackStack(null);
   ft.commit();
   }
   ```

Comment: rotating the image is the culprit which result `out of memory exception`

Comment: are yiu using image loader class for downloading images?

Comment: @Pankaj no I am simply copying image from the gallery to app's external files dir. See the code I added above.

Comment: @SpringBreaker But wouldn't `recycle` the bitmap take care of that problem?

Comment: Increase your Required Size and scale variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:largeHeap="true"` in Manifest File. Maybe this solve your problem.